# Laravel5.2 with auth2.0 not working

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I have set up auth server with Laravel5.2 as following tutorial.
http://discountry.github.io/tutorial/2016/02/20/Laravel-RESTful-Oauth2/

All the things done well. But finally when I call a url `http://localhost/myprojectname/public/oauth/access_token` using postman rest client it is not working.

I get

> 500 internal server error is getting

Fixed the errors that loged in apache error log.now it gives following error when I try to get access token.

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

What is the wrong that I have done ?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: 500 internal server error is getting

Comment: I'm sure this mean there is an error on server's side. Do you have access to the error log? You could try `find /my_path/ -mtime -1` to look for recently modified / created log files.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I run the command you have asked. /my_path/ is my project path.right? I get the list of files that are in project folder.

Comment: Maybe you could also try from the root, if server not too big: `find /var -mtime -1 -name "*log*" -type f 2>/dev/null`; you may need to adapt `var` my command was to help you find the log files, then look for relevant error in them that will permit solving your issue. Does the tutorial says where server error might be? The question is to find relevant error?

Comment: fixed the errors that loged in apache error log.now it gives following error when I try to get access token. `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:`